# Edit of Javascript required to add fade in/fade out effect please

Tags: javascript, html, effects, fadein, fadeout

Is it possible to add a fade in fade out effect to this javascript? At the moment it just loads an image to another div upon hover of first div but with no effect. Thanks in advance.

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript"> 
    function changeDisplay(bgImageURL)
    {
            var displayDiv = document.getElementById("displayDiv");


        // draw popup image in the div
        displayDiv.innerHTML = 
            '<a class="popup1" href="#v"><img src="' + bgImageURL+ '" alt="" /></a>';
        // show the display in case it was hidden before
        displayDiv.style.visibility = "visible";
    }

    function hideDisplay()
    {
        var displayDiv = document.getElementById("displayDiv");

        // hide it when the mouse rolls off the thumbnail
        displayDiv.style.visibility = "hidden";
    }

    </script>
```

Comment: Can you post your relevant HTML as well

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery

http://api.jquery.com/fadeIn/

```
<div id="fade"></div> <!-- make sure this is initially hidden -->

<script type="text/javascript">
  $('#fade').fadeIn('slow', function() {
    // When animation is complete, it runs this function
  });
</script>
```

`fadeOut`: http://api.jquery.com/fadeOut/

Answer (score 0):

simple change in your existing code

```
include jquery plugin before your javascript code and change
```

display function

```
displayDiv.style.visibility = "visible"; to  displayDiv.fadeIn('slow');
```

hide function

```
displayDiv.style.visibility = "visible"; to displayDiv.fadeOut();
```